# Using for loop in least cost path analysis using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, loop

I am doing a least cost path analysis. I need to create a for loop that will run 3 times and select the correct weight from each of the two lists (slope and land).

```
Slope = [10, 20, 30]
Land = [30, 20, 10]

import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = (c:\)
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#------------------------------------------------- Times calculation

outTimes10 = Times("Slope",10)
outTimes20 = Times("Slope",20)
outTimes30 = Times("Slope",30)

#------------------------------------------------- Times calculation

outland30 = Times("land_tif", 30)
outland20 = Times("land_tif", 20)
outland10 = Times("land_tif", 10)

#------------------------------------------------- Added two raster together

outPlus1030 = Plus("outTimes10", "outland30")
outPlus2020 = Plus("outTimes20", "outland20")
outPlus3010 = Plus("outTimes30", "outland10")

#------------------------------------------------- Cost Back link

outBacklink = CostBackLink("Hiker.shp","outPlus1030", 100000, 
                           "c:/sapyexamples/output/distRast")

pair1bl="CostBac_shp1"
pair2bl="CostBac_shp2"
pair3bl="CostBac_shp3"

#------------------------------------------------- Cost distance

outCostDist = CostDistance("Hiker.shp", "slope", 200000, "pair1bl")

pair1cd="CostDis_shp1"
pair2cd="CostDis_shp2"
pair3cd="CostDis_shp3"

#------------------------------------------------- Least cost path

outCostPath = CostPath("Hiker.shp", "outplus1030", "pair1bl", "EACH_CELL")

path1="CostPat_shp1"
path2="CostPat_shp2"
path3="CostPat_shp3"
```

I am new to python. I need help with creating a for loop that will select numbers from the two list do the times calculation, plus calculation, cost backlink, cost distance, and least cost path.

I do not know how to direct the output of the calculation to be saved in a different file name everytime the loop runs.

Answer (score 1):

You can [zip the lists](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) together and iterate over each slopevalue, landvalue and a name:

```
#More code above
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

Slope = [10, 20, 30]
Land = [30, 20, 10]
Name = ['Out1','Out2','Out3']

for slopeval,landval,name in zip(Slope,Land,Name):
    outTimes = Times("Slope",slopeval)
    outTimes.save('outTimes.tif') #Dont know if saving is required or if it is possible to use the raster object as input to next steps.
    outland = Times("land_tif", landval)
    outland.save('outland.tif')
    outPlus = Plus('outTimes.tif', 'outland.tif')
    outPlus.save('outplus.tif')
    outBacklink = CostBackLink("Hiker.shp","outplus", 100000, 
                               "c:/sapyexamples/output/{0}".format(name+'.tif'))
    #More code here
```

Comment: Never used that zip() function, nice example bringing 3 values together, thanks!

Comment: I get the error zip argument #1 must support iteration. How to fix this error? I never tried this before. @BERA